# 'font' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Drawing' code bc30560

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

Updated some  NUGET packages today and also installed Itext7 on a dev machine. VS 2022. Installed Itext7 package.

When I rebuilt the project it threw 38 errors, most of them 'font' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Drawing'    code bc30560.  Font & systemcolors  were the two main errors.  I removed the Itext7 packages .

I had them all fully named:(example Below)

Me.TBtotalCk.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))

and yet it's telling me "System.Drawing.Font"  is ambiguous. Even if I use an Imports statement. System.Drawing works but System.Drawing.Font throws the same error, ambiguous.

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Eliminate the Imports statement(s) and use fully-qualified names or use an alias. See [Imports Statement (.NET Namespace and Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type)

Comment: Already tired all the above. No Go but thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this from time to time. This is counter-intuitive but try this.

Remove all of the qualifiers:

Me.TBtotalCk.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10.0!, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))

Check for any syntax errors. If found hover and click on the "suggested fix" link. This should tell you what is confusing the system.

Hope this helps.